# Google speech recognition causing slow down

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, speech

I am using google chrome text to speech in my web app. I press `c` to start listening, and `c` again to stop.

I pressed it a few times and my mac's Activity Monitor was showing `Google Chrome Helper` racking up CPU usage. The more I clicked start/stop, the more the helper's usage seemed to grow.

I read that the helper is an interface for chrome plugins and APIs, so it'd seem that there is a correlation to starting/stopping the recognition object.

I'd like to know why starting/stopping the speech event would rack up CPU usage as `recognition.stop()` should kill the process. Is there a method I should be using to actually kill the process? `speechSynthesis` has `speechSynthesis.cancel();` to kill it- is `stop()` the same?

```
       recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition(),
          ...

        api.speak = function (e) {
            if (speaking) {
                speaking = false;
                this.stop_recognition(e);
            } else {
                speaking = true;
                this.start_recognition(e);
            }
        };

        api.stop_recognition (event) { 
            recognition.stop();
        };
```

---

```
        if (key === 'c') {
            $('#command_box').toggle('slow', function () {
                Utilities.STT.speak();
            });
        }
```

Comment: Instead of using stop(), why dont you just use `pause` instead.... right now you are basically starting and stopping which is tedious process. So instead, start it and then whenever you want to stop listening, pause it.

Comment: If you are trying to do a text to speech, why are you using a `webkitSpeechRecognition()`?? I think it has to be `webkitSpeechSynthesis`??